# How to dynamic image URL in a WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

[image: Click here see image]

How to dynamic image URL in a WordPress plugin?

Comment: WTF? What do you want exactly? Nobody understands what you try to say.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get the featured image's URL:

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'large' ); ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
 <?php } ?>
```